# Referencing properties with for_each in modules and count in the resource

Tags: azure, terraform

Here is my shortened code:

`variable.tf`:

```
variable "vm_avd" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    avd-std = {
      vm_count = "2"
      ### Interface Vars
      subnet_id = "AD"
    }
    avd-gpu = {
      vm_count = "2"
      ### Interface Vars
      subnet_id = "AD"
    }
  }
}

variable "vm_server" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    srv-std = {
      vm_count = "2"
      ### Interface Vars
      subnet_id = "AD"
    }
  }
}
```

`if.tf`:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "if" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = var.private_ip_address_allocation == "Static" ? "if_${var.if_name}_${replace(var.private_ip_address, ".", "")}_${format("%02d", count.index)}" : "if_${var.if_name}_${format("%02d", count.index)}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "if_ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_version    = var.private_ip_address_version
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.private_ip_address_allocation
    private_ip_address            = var.private_ip_address
  }
}
output "if_name" {
  value = azurerm_network_interface.if[*].name
}
output "if_id" {
  value = azurerm_network_interface.if[*].id
}
```

`main.tf`:

```
module "vm" {
  for_each              = merge(var.vm_server, var.vm_avd)
  vm_name               = each.key
  vm_count              = each.value["vm_count"]
  network_interface_ids = module.if[each.key].if_id
}

module "if" {
  for_each  = merge(var.vm_server, var.vm_avd)
  vm_count  = each.value["vm_count"]
  if_name   = each.key
  subnet_id = module.snet[each.value["subnet_id"]].snet_id
}
```

Is there a possibility to reference in a `for_each` loop the correct `count` object for dependent resources?

I'm creating Terraform modules for Azure and I want to build a structure that is highly flexible and easy to fill for everyone.

Therefore I build a root file with a single module call for each resource and I have a single main variables file which should be filled with values which are looped through.

All related resource variables are defined in the same variables object, so for a VM a variable VM is created and filled with VM details, NIC details and extension details. The single modules run through the same variables for VM, NIC and extensions which is, in general, running fine.

I can reference the `subnet_id` for the network interfaces nicely but as soon as I use a `count` operator in the resource I don't know how the correctly get the network interface ID of the correct interface for the correct VM.

Now I ran into the problem that I use for_each in my module call and I want to have the option to use count in my resource definition too. It is working but when I build e.g. virtual machines, I get the problem that I cannot reference to the correct network interfaces.
Atm all my interfaces are connected to the same VM and the 2nd VM cannot be build. Same goes for extensions and any possible multiple objects tho.

I tried several module calls but the first VM got all the interfaces every time. I tried with the Star character in the NIC module call or with the network interface ID.
If this is not possible at all, I thought of a solution with building the network interface ID itself with its original form.

I also checked if there is a possibility to build an array with the `for_each` and count elements but I couldn't find any way to build arrays out of number variables in terraform, like the normal "for 1 to 5 do".
If you know of any way to do this, I would be grateful too.

Comment: What is `var.vm_server`? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: Have you defined proper outputs in the modules so you can reference them?

Comment: Yes, I added the resource defintion aswell in this post.

Comment: So your `vm` module expects multiple interfaces to be passed to it based on this: `network_interface_ids`?

Comment: It expects a list of IDs but I only want to pass 1 interface, formatted as list element. Atm I plan with only one interface per VM.

Comment: I think this is far too complex to be answered in an SO question. In short, it's never a good idea to mix `count` and `for_each`. The easiest way to fix this probably would be to call the module multiple times and lose the `count` in the `if` module while taking care to fix the outputs in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a typo when you try to simplify the question, but in your variables you have:

```
variable vm_avd { default = { avd-std = {...}} }
variable vm_server { default = { avd-std = {...}} }
```

in your main tf you have:

```
merge(var.vm_server, var.vm_avd)
```

since the key is the same, one will override the other, if you are using the default value, it might result in the behaviour you are suggesting, consider changing the key name to server-std?

Comment: Sry, I just copied the text in here and didn't align to the real script, I will update the description here to the correct state..

Comment: I will reiterate what @marko-e commented before, it doesn't sound a good idea to mix count and for_each, if for nothing else, just not to have extra complexity, and making it harder to maintain.

Comment: The general idea is to build this a single time and after that you only have to add variables and the infrastructure is build autoamtically. No editing of modules or resources ever again. To accomplish that I need to be flexible when creating resources which includes building single VMs with for_each and multiple AVD VMs with count as I don't want to add every dingle avd VM as Variable entry. If this is not possible I need to find another solution.

Comment: you could try to build a map instead of an array, like { count_index_1 = count_index_1_value, .... , count_index_x = count_index_x_value} and iterate from it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correclty:
For example I don't want to write every AVD VM down in my variable, when I deploy 10+ VMs of the same kind with just an increasing name. For servers and different kind of AVD VMs I use the map variable and iterate through every entry with for_each so in the end it should be a mix of for_each with specific VMs and count for similar VMs, if this is possible.

Comment: To achieve what you are trying to do, I would try to create a map with the multiplication of the VMs x Count so you can get a connection between count_index and VMs, { count_index_1 = VM1, .... , count_index_x = VMY} and then create the resources based on this map, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with simply providing the whole element array, e.g. from VM, to the variable for the ID and the reference the correct VM with the count index:

virtual_machine_id         = var.vm_id[count.index]

As i run through the same Count in other ressources, I get the correct order of the elements for referencing :)